# Problem with relative grading system?

Tags: phd, grading

My college (IIT) follows a relative grading system and each professor was given freedom in choosing how to grade the students.

As far as I know, Some professors give 5 students (less than 8 percent of the batch) the grade of S and others give A grade to 6-7 people in the class. I am looking for to apply for Phd, where I see colleges asking for a certain percentage in marks, like X percent in a taught module.

It is almost impossible for me to know how much I scored in a particular subject as we were just given relative grading. How should this issue can be resolved?

Comment: Sorry, explain what you mean by "relative grading".

Comment: "As far as I know" so without real evidence what do you expect?

Comment: Actually, as I mentioned, my university provides complete freedom to professors in choosing grades. So some professors go on like top 5% to be awarded S grade and som goes on like the first 6-7 scores get distinction grade. It is totally up to them and no professor neither informs the students about their real score, nor they clarify our rank within our batch. All we got is grade.

Answer (score 0):

I think grad schools are used to dealing with different grading schemes.  This is one reason, why GREs exist also.  But they can probably infer that top 10-20% is an A.  Bottom 50% is bad, etc.  Maybe even implicitly compensating for differences in how competitive the undergrad is.

Maybe grad schools aren't perfect but they seem to even be able to (in the US) evaluate students from all over the globe to try to pick the better ones.  Although even the US is very different from school to school.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to contact the department and just ask them how they'd like you to handle this. They have perfect information over their own preferences.